# License Key Generator Probability of Collision

Tags: java, statistics

I've written code that generates a license key.

*It must be A-Z or 0-9 (36 possibilities)

*The first 4 digits are always MKDC, the next 16 are randomly generated

I want to learn how I can calculate the probability of collision (2 generated licenses being identical).

```
public class Random {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String licensestring = "MKDC-";
    char license[]  = {
        'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'
    };

    int x = 0;
    while (x < 16){
        java.security.SecureRandom rand = new java.security.SecureRandom();
        int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(36);
        licensestring = licensestring + license[randomNumber];
        x = x + 1;
        if (x == 4 || x == 8 || x == 12){
            licensestring = licensestring + "-";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(licensestring);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two generated licenses, the variable characters of one have to match the variable characters of the other. This is equal to a probability of

[image: 1/36^16]

This value is roughly 0.00000000000000000000000125.

However, for multiple licenses, the probability increases. For n licenses, the probability is:

[image: 36^16 PERMUTE n, all over 36^(16n)]

The key space is so vastly huge that Wolfram|alpha is [unable to determine](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%2836%5E16%29+permute+10000%29%29%29%2F%2836%5E%2816*10000%29%29%29) the collision probability using current methods for a reasonable number of keys.

Comment: You beat me by 3 seconds AND got the superscript formatting.  Award this the answer.

Comment: Should I worry about this frequency level of collisions, or is it fine that 1.25% of the time I'll have to run the code again due to that license already existing in the database?

Comment: @Dave How'd you get 1.25%? The probability of two licenses colliding is `0.000000000000000000000001256492751965832466545784500576187130695567024443641674`. This is so vastly small that simply checking for a duplicate, and handling it, without worrying at all about performance, is going to be optimal.

Comment: I must have misinterpreted the windows calculator results, it says 1.2564927519658324665457845005762e-25. oh i see, 25 is the leading number of 0s.

Comment: @Dave Yep, the e is scientific notation. A quick way to eyeball that is to know that 1.25% is greater than 1/100, while the fraction I gave is vastly smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Am I oversimplifying this by saying the answer is (1/36)^16 ?